# Generate OpenSSL configuration file from certificate

Tags: linux, security, ssl, certificate, openssl

I have a certificate and I want to create an OpenSSL configuration file from it (I'm trying to follow the workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152891/chrome-not-trust-https-and-show-err-ssl-server-cert-bad-format)). Is there any automatic way to do it?

I mean, from an X509 certificate, using `openssl` or any other tool, I'd like to create a file like:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions = v3_req
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
C = TW
ST = Taiwan
L = Taipei
O = CR
OU = It
CN = html_12
[v3_req]
keyUsage = keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[...]
```

Comment: You didn't provide information on the workaround.  Helpful if you specify you want to create what appears to be an OpenSSL configuration file.

Comment: Thank you Ramhound, I've updated the question with the link.